# Android: How to make circle-shaped Camera Preview?

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, preview

How can I create circle/oval-shaped or round-cornered Camera Preview like this (the circle in the middle should be camera preview)?

[image]

The London image represents rest of the ui with buttons and views, so **it has to be visible** whole and that's why I cannot use solutions like add `android:background` as a shape rectangle with radius like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="50dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

and when I try to set `android:background` as oval xml to the SurfaceView, it doesn't work either:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"/>

    <stroke
        android:color="#FF000000"
        android:width="2dp" />
</shape>
```

If it is possible to somehow extend SurfaceView and use it, what should I rewrite please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CardView to a house your textureView or surfaceArea like this.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cameraWrapper"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="360dp"
        android:foreground="@drawable/background_camera_overlay_circle_inactive"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:padding="-20dp">

        <com.mobile.myapp.CustomViews.CameraSourcePreview //you can use SurfaceView, TextView, ImageView
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"/></androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The key things to note.

- `cornerRadius` is set to 360 to get the CardView to have a round shape
- `cardElevation` is set to zero to remove elevation, thereby making the CardView flat
- `padding` is set to a negative value so that the child view is tucked in nicely
- `layout_width` and `layout_height` values of the child view are bigger than that of the cardView.
- The CardView has a foreground property that has been set to a drawable file `background_camera_overlay_circle`, which simply draws the circle border

The content of `background_camera_overlay_circle`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/colorRed_FB7B7B"/>
  </shape>
```

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

hmm i think the easiest way is by put an imageView on top of your SurfaceView
example by xml:

```
<RelativeLayout ....>
  <SurfaceView ... />
  <ImageView ... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the background image (London) represents my UI, these things have to be in background.

Comment: Why do they have to be in the background?  Why can't you make a transparent circular hole with that ImageView and let the SurfaceView's surface show through it?  (Or just use draw on the SurfaceView's View, which is nothing but a transparent rectangle.)

Comment: oops sorry to mention, the imageview contain an image that have a transparent circle, you could use a PNG image

Comment: @2rec Have you found the solution yet? I'm trying to create a circle camera preview too.

Comment: @Sunshinetpu Not yet, have you?

Comment: @2rec Me too. So sad.